# is there a way to wait for an a tag element that could be one of two based on their href value in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

So I'm not sure if this practically valid, but was wondering if there's a way in selenium to wait for an <a tag - out of two based on their href value or the text contained after the tag closes.
What I'm trying to do is to power up this page https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges, iterate through the exchanges links, visit each one of them, then click on the about tab of each of those newly opened pages as they contain the info to be extracted. The code actually worked up until halfway through when it failed to identify the tab properly through a StaleElementException and elementNotFound as I did it through driver.find_element_by_text.

The problem is that the 'about' tab changes from one page to the other, so it's either //ul[@role='tablist']/li[3] or li[2], and that's why I'm trying to wait and click on the right element based on its href value. That is since one of the a tags on the page href's value contains the text # about ---> //ul[@role='tablist']/li[3]/a

Apologies if it wasn't straightforward but I was trying to pinpoint what the issue was until recently :)

This is the code that I've attempted so far if anyone can gratefully point me in the right direction

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException



webdriver = '/Users/karimnabil/projects/selenium_js/chromedriver-1'

driver = Chrome(webdriver)

num_of_pages = 4
exchanges_list = []
names_list = []
websites_list = []
emails_list = []
years_list = []
countries_list = []
twitter_list = []


for i in range(num_of_pages):

    url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges?page=' + str(i+1)
    driver.get(url)

    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@data-target='exchanges-list.tableRows']/tr/td[2]/div/span[2]/a")
    links = [url.get_attribute('href') for url in links]
    time.sleep(0.5)

    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
        



        wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.XPATH, "//ul[@role='tablist']/li[position()=2 or position()=3]/a"), '#about'))
       

        try:
            name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='exchange-details-header-content']/div/h1").text
            website = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='row no-gutters']/div[8]/a").get_attribute('href')
            email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='row no-gutters']/div[9]/a").get_attribute('href')
            year_est = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='row no-gutters']/div[10]").text
            inc_country = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='row no-gutters']/div[12]").text
            twitter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='row no-gutters']/div[16]/div[2]/div[2]/a").get_attribute('title')
        except:
            pass
        try:
            print('---------------')
            print('exchange name is : {}'.format(name))
            print('exchange website is : {}'.format(website))
            print('exchange email is : {}'.format(email))
            print('exchange established in year: {}'.format(year_est))
            print('exchange incorporated in : {}'.format(Inc_country))
            print('exchange twitter handle is: {}'.format(twitter))
        except:
            pass

        try:
            names_list.append(name)
            websites_list.append(website)
            emails_list.append(email)
            years_list.append(year_est)
            countries_list.append(Inc_country)
            twitter_list.append(twitter)
        except:
            pass
        

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names_list, websites_list,emails_list, years_list, countries_list, twitter_list)), columns=['Ex_Names', 'Website', 'Support Email', 'Inc Year', 'Inc Country', 'Twitter Handle' ])

CoinGecko2_data = df.to_csv('CoinGecko4.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: If you know the href just wait for: `//a[contains(@href, 'my-href')]`

Comment: @pguardiario Can't believe how simple the fix was, very much appreciated brother :) Can you edit your comment as an answer to mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the href just wait for: `//a[contains(@href, 'my-href')]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sue if there is any but you can create your custom wait. Here is an example:

https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/waitcustom